# Region measure of a list of points

Tags: functions, regions

Regardless of the coordinate values of the points, the output of `RegionMeasure` is the same, e.g:

```
{RegionMeasure[Point[{{0, 0, 0}, {8, 8, 8}}]], 
 RegionCentroid[Point[{{0, 0, 0}, {8, 8, 8}}]]}
```

> ```
> {2, {4, 4, 4}}
> ```

```
{RegionMeasure[Point[{{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, {1.75, 1.75, 1.75}}]], 
 RegionCentroid[Point[{{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, {1.75, 1.75, 1.75}}]]}
```

> ```
> {2., {1.125, 1.125, 1.125}}
> ```

Comment: The `RegionMeasure` of a discrete point cloud is of course the counting measure (because `RegionDimension[Point[{{0, 0, 0}, {8, 8, 8}}]]` returns `0`). And for two points it is equal to `2`, no matter what the coordinates are.

Comment: Maybe you want `RegionMeasure[Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {8, 8, 8}}]]` instead?

Comment: @Henrick Schumacher.Understood. Thank you  so much!

Answer (score 2):

The comment of Henrick Schumacher answered my question so I am posting it here:
The `RegionMeasure` of a discrete point cloud is of course the counting measure (because `RegionDimension[Point[{{0, 0, 0}, {8, 8, 8}}]]` returns 0). And for two points it is equal to 2, no matter what the coordinates are.